# How to package and deploy a C# desktop application with a SQL Server 2012 database in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-2012

I have created a database application using C# in Visual Studio 2013. It uses SQL Server 2012. I don't know how to package my database in the `.msi` package for this application. Please help me in writing a script to create the database and setup its connection strings. So that I can install and run the app using SQL Server on any other PC besides my own computer where I am developing the app.

Comment: You will also need to install SQLServer, which has it's own installer. Read up on configuring dependencies in your installer project and how to configure the installer to copy specific files and even run script to restored databases. The base (MSDN atricle)[https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/206sadcd%28v=vs.100%29.aspx]

Comment: I have installed Sql Server but the question is how to write Script for creating Database and tables and package them in an .msi package so that I can Install the application and database is setup automatically

Comment: The article you referred says No Content Found....

Comment: Apologies, there was a ] that slipped into the link, the correct one:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/206sadcd%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The way I saw it in a commercial project was:

1. Create an msi installer for your own application using [WiX](http://wixtoolset.org/).
2. Get the msi package for SQL server installation.
3. Create custom installer in wix or in a programming language you know. It will use **Deployment Tools Foundation** to run SQL msi and your app msi.
4. Pack it all into [nsis](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) package so you have a single Installer.exe file as an output.

Also check:

- http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/bundle/
- google for "unattended sql server install"